# How to allow users to create their own website within my domain?

Tags: theme-development, multisite, theme-customizer, front-end

I want to create a wedding website builder similar to theknot or withjoy.com. I want to provide the following features -

1. User should be able to choose their own url slug
2. User should have a frontend website builder
3. User should be able to select a predefined theme

Please let me know how can I achieve this using WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that WordPress can handle quite well in multisite mode. I found that it helps to use plugins to handle the creation of new blogs. For example, in the last multisite I was involved with, they used CBOX (commons in a box) to run BuddyPress, one of the features was that when a user made a new group, they could add a blog to it. This tied the groups/social side of things together with the blogging side.

For speculation of which plugins to use, I think that probably falls outside of the scope of this site due to being pretty much a matter of opinion. Your best bet is to look into all the available plugins. There are endless reviews you can find via Google.

**To answer your points in order:**

1. WordPress multisite can handle this for you.
2. You will need a plugin. You may end up paying money for it.
3. That's pretty much baked into WordPress, plugins can refine this if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Even I've enabled multisite for my website. But I'm confused with the website builder. Is there any website builder that user can use it from the frontend and design their page without going to wp admin? Does elementor, divi or any other website builder support this?

Comment: The fastest way to find out is to go to the websites for elementor, divi, etc. and check the documentation. If in doubt, ask in their support forum (or however they support users).